# Cut japanese string in japanese + english tring php code

Tags: php, cjk

I have string

```
$string = 'Nguyễn handsome 日本';
```

And I want to cut string with japanese and utf-8 (English)

```
echo $string1;  //string1 = 日本;
```

or

```
$string = 'Nguyễn handsome' // remove japanese language
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: apply the same concept `echo preg_replace('/[\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Han}]+/u', '', $string);`. time to step up your google fu :p

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you mean, but `mb_ereg_replace` is like `preg_replace` but with multi-byte (UTF-8) support. Is that what you're looking for?

```php
echo mb_ereg_replace("/[a-zA-Z0-9\x{3041}-\x{3096}\x{30a1}-\x{30fc}\x{4e00}-\x{9faf}]$/u", "", $string1);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! but doesn't work

Comment: @Ng.Hau I removed the `^` and `$` from the pattern, please try my answer again, it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I will go with something like this (add the specials characters that you want to replace ie (or use this to make white spaces):

```
      public function unwantedCharset($string)
    {
        $unwanted_array = array(    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
            'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
            'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
            'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
            'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );
        $string =   strtr($string , $unwanted_array);
        return $string; 
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! but we can check specials with '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\x' and japanese language '/^[\x{3041}-\x{3096}\x{30a1}-\x{30fc}\x{4e00}-\x{9faf}]+$/u'.